# Why cannot I directly use returned pointer as parameter in function call of insert?

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, function-parameter

Here's the prototype of the function:

```cpp
void BinaryDimonTree::insert(int x, int y, int level, TreeNode *&cur)
```

in the function, I tried to call:

```
insert(x, y, ++level, cur->getLeftChild());
```

and here's `getLeftChild`:

```
TreeNode* TreeNode::getLeftChild() const {
    return this->left;
}
```

Then, it reports an error:

> no instance of overloaded function "BinaryDimonTree::insert" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (int, int, int, TreeNode *)

If I change my code this way:

```
TreeNode *child = cur->getLeftChild();
insert(x, y, ++level, child);
```

No error would be reported.

I wonder why this problem occurs and how to solve it if I want to directly use the function return value as the parameter?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can't use an implicit temp as a reference argument. How would you refer to it after the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last argument of your `insert` function is non-const reference to a pointer. In the call:

```
insert(x, y, ++level, cur->getLeftChild());
```

the last argument is a temporary value of `TreeNode *` type, that cannot bind to the `TreeNode * &`. You can find a good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)